# Google Sheets Error: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveCell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

Trying to move data from one sheet to another if two sets of data in each sheet corresponds (the date in this case). I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveRange
```

I've seen some things to suggest I might not be pulling through from the sheet I've named, or that it's pulling through the value wrong? Not sure, any advice would be great.

Code:

```js
function pullData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dateCell = inputSheet.getActiveCell("C2").getValue();
  var inputRange = inputSheet.getActiveRange("C6:Z999");
  var currentRange = currentSheet.getActiveRange("C6:Z999");

  if (dateCell == currentSheet.getActiveCell("B2").getValue()){
    var inputRows = inputRange.getNumRows();
    var inputCols = inputRange.getNumColumns();
    for (var i = 1; i <= inputRows; i++) {
      for (var j = 1; j <= inputCols; j++) {
        var inputValue = inputRange.getCell(i,j).getValue();
        var currentValue = currentRange.getCell(i,j).setValue(inputValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: I did not unfortunately, as I completely changed my approach to the function and created a new solution entirely, never encountering this error again, so no idea what caused it. Apologies that this question won't be of much help to others.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

- When the value of cell "C2" of the sheet `Input` is the same with the value of cell "B2 of the active sheet, you want to copy the values of cells "C6:Z999" of the sheet `Input` to the cells "C6:Z999" of the active sheet.
- You want to know the reason of the following error message.

  - `Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveRange`

### Modification points:

- `getActiveRange()` has no arguments. But you use the arguments. I think that the reason of your error message is this.
- Also, `getActiveCell()` has no arguments. So in your script, I think that an error occurs at `var dateCell = inputSheet.getActiveCell("C2").getValue();`. From this situation, I thought that your tested script might be different from the script in your question.
- When I saw the flow of your script, I thought that your goal might be as follows.

  - When the value of cell "C2" of the sheet `Input` is the same with the value of cell "B2 of the active sheet, you want to copy the values of cells "C6:Z999" of the sheet `Input` to the cells "C6:Z999" of the active sheet.
  - If my understanding is correct, `getActiveCell("C2")`, `getActiveRange("C6:Z999")` and `getActiveCell("B2")` might be `getRange("C2")`, `getRange("C6:Z999")` and `getRange("B2")`, respectively.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script is modified for removing the error message.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var dateCell = inputSheet.getActiveCell("C2").getValue();
var inputRange = inputSheet.getActiveRange("C6:Z999");
var currentRange = currentSheet.getActiveRange("C6:Z999");

if (dateCell == currentSheet.getActiveCell("B2").getValue()){
```

To:

```
var dateCell = inputSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
var inputRange = inputSheet.getRange("C6:Z9");
var currentRange = currentSheet.getRange("C6:Z9");

if (dateCell == currentSheet.getRange("B2").getValue()){
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, your script is modified by reducing the process cost. In your current script, `getValue()` and `setValue()` are used in the for loop. In this case, when `inputRows` and `inputCols` are large, the process cost will be high. So in this pattern, I would like to propose to reduce the cost.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows. In this modification, the values of cells "C6:Z999" of the sheet `Input` are copied to the cells "C6:Z999" of the active sheet using `copyTo`. By this, your goal can be achieved without using the for loop.

```
function pullData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Input");
  var currentSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dateCell = inputSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var inputRange = inputSheet.getRange("C6:Z9");
  var currentRange = currentSheet.getRange("C6:Z9");

  if (dateCell == currentSheet.getRange("B2").getValue()){
    inputRange.copyTo(currentRange, {contentsOnly:true});  // Modified
  }
}
```

### References:

- [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverange)
- [getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options)